# How to handle action events between components in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component that is reused in other components but there is a problem that the code handle action events (e.g: onDelete) are repeated too many times. I have to handle `onDelete` in all places where PostCard is used even though the logic code makes no difference except at the Home page. So is there any way I can avoid the repetition of handleDelete? Respect any ideas. I'm new to React.js, hope you guys can help me!

PostCard component:

```
 function PostCard ({ item, onDelete }) => {
    return (
      <div onClick={() => onDelete(item.id)}>{item.title}</div>
    )
 }
```

PostCard using in Home page:

```
 const HomePage = () => {

   function handleDelete() {
      // only mutate array to re-render list (not redirect)
   }

   return (
      <>
        {postList.map(post => (
           <PostCard item={post} onDelete={handleDelete} />
        ))}
      </>
   )
  
 }
```

PostCard using in detail page:

```
 const DetailPage = () => {
   function handleDelete() {
      // redirect to home page after delete
   }

   return (        
      <PostCard item={post} onDelete={handleDelete} />
   )
  
 }
```

PostCard using in another page:

```
 const AnotherPage = () => {
   function handleDelete() {
      // redirect to home page after delete
   }

   return (        
      <PostCard item={post} onDelete={handleDelete} />
   )
  
 }
```

Comment: you want to delete from state or from database?

Comment: @Hatana I want to delete from state and send request to database. Hi Hatana , If my question is difficult to understand please let me know, I will try to clarify the problem

Comment: no that's ok have a look I added an answer give me feedbacks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a context on a higer level than those components so you can pass the `postList` state and `handleDelete` function as context to them for example:

```js
const App = () => {
  export const PostContext = createContext();
  const [postList, setPostList] = useState([]);
  const handleDelete = (postId) => {
    // delete logic
  };
//...
  return (
    <PostContext.Provider value={{ postList, handleDelete }}>
      //..
    </PostContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

and from your components :

```js
const PostCard = ({ item }) => {
  const { handleDelete } = useContext(PostContext); // you have to import it from App
  return (
    <div onClick={() => handleDelete(item.id)}>{item.title}</div>
  );
};
```

when it is a component from which you want to navigate you just add the redirection code:

```js
onClick={() => {
 handleDelete(item.id)
 // navigation
}}
```

learn more [here](https://react.dev/reference/react/useContext) about `useContext`